# Not Able to Import Python Library "Pytube" for my chrome extension using Pyscript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, pytube, pyscript

I took code from this repository: [https://github.com/Arinze1020/pyscript-local-runtime/tree/master]

```
PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/lib/python3.10/asyncio/futures.py", line 201, in result raise 
self._exception File "/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in 
__step result = coro.send(None) File "/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 506, in eval_code_async await CodeRunner( 
File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 357, in 
run_async coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 12, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'
```

**Popup.html**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
    <title>Playlist length calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <py-config>
      [[runtimes]]
      src = "runtime/pyodide.js"
      name = "pyodide-0.21.3"
      lang = "python"
    </py-config>
    <link rel="icon" type="icons/png" href="/icon-128.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="runtime/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="/setup.py"></script>
    <script defer src="runtime/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <h4 id="datetime"></h4>
    <!-- Python code below is intentionally left-aligned to utilise full width  -->
    <py-script src="pytube/__main__.py">
    from js import document as popup  # DOM for this popup page
    from pytube import YouTube

    link = input("Enter YouTube Playlist URL: ")

    yt_playlist = Playlist(link) 

    </py-script>
    <py-repl> 
    text = "This is a REPL session.<br>"
    text += "You can add several lines of Python<br>"
    text += "Then just press Shift-ENTER to run!"
    print(text.upper())
    </py-repl>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried downloading the Pytube and add the extension folder but same error kept coming. Please explain in Leymann terms as I am new to Web development. There is nothing on the internet on how to import library in python in pyscript for chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

To add Python packages to your page for PyScript to use, add them to the `packages` key in your `<py-config>` tag. Here's [an example](https://pyscript.recipes/2023.05.1/basic/installing-packages/):

```ini
<py-config>
    packages = ['astropy', 'pyyaml', 'https://example.com/files/someWheel-py3-none-any.whl']
    # packages can be from PyPI, Pyodide Packages, or Pyothon wheels
</py-config>
```

It's possible packages won't be usable in the context of PyScript/Pyodide, but this is the way to install the ones that can.